# keep getting Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name. error

Tags: django

I want to implement password reset functionality on my web page but I am getting `NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password_reset/ Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`  error. please help me to solve this error

url.py Code:

```
app_name="accounts"
urlpatterns=[


path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="password_reset.html",success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done')), name='password_reset'),

  path('password_reset_done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),

 path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="password_reset_confirm.html",success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_complete')), 
 name="password_reset_confirm"),

path('reset_password_complete/', 
    auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="password_reset_done.html"), name="password_reset_complete"),
```

]

passwrd_reset.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Password Reset Page{% endblock %} 
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
<div class="row mt-5 pt-3">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        <div class="card my-3 shadow">
            <div class="card-body">
<h4>Password Reset Page</h4>
                <hr>
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    Enter email and a mail will be sent with instructions to reset password
                </div>
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Reset Password">
 </form>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock body%}

Additional info about me apps
I have two apps one is dashboard and anther is accounts I want to implement this in my accounts app

Comment: Please check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66406530/keep-getting-this-error-of-reverse-for-password-reset-confirm-not-found-pass

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep getting this error of Reverse for 'password\_reset\_confirm' not found. 'password\_reset\_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66406530/keep-getting-this-error-of-reverse-for-password-reset-confirm-not-found-pass)

Comment: @ Ashish Nautiyal and @ Abdul Aziz Barkat before posting this question I have tried this solution but this answer does not work for me

Comment: I have tried paasword_reset_confirm url like this                                                             `path(
        'password_reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name='reset_password_confirm.html',
            success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_complete')
        ),
        name='password_reset_confirm'
    ),`

Comment: but this is not working for me I still am getting the same error

Comment: I am also getting this with the above error which I have mentioned in my asked question, Is there anything to do in the password_reset.html file  `Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\myProjects\yearlyproject\proenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\registration\password_reset_email.html, error at line 6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `core` app (where you have `settings.py`). Go to your `urls.py` file and paste:

```
path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

Note you have to import `include` from `django.urls`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to your main url.py located in the same folder as the settings.py
2. Import include from django.urls (**from django.urls import include**)
3. Add the line below to urlpatterns
   **path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),**

Reload the server and retry

Answer (score 0):

Check your html file names. Is there a password_reset_confirm.html file?

Comment: yes I have a password_reset_confirm.html